# Please advise on the Python regular expression

Tags: python, regex, split

```
message = <@U0104FGR7SL> test111 <@U0106LSJ> test33
```

There is the above string.

Based on the reference letter corresponding to the pattern <@U......>

I'd like to split the text.

I'd like to cut it by a pattern.

```
regex = re.compile("<@U[^>]+>")

match = regex.split (message)
```

If I do this, I get a "test, test22"

```
<@U0104FGR7SL> test111 
<@U0106LSJ> test33
```

I'd like to split it this way.

Please advise me what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
import re
message = "<@U0104FGR7SL> test111 <@U0106LSJ> test33"
matches = re.findall("<\S+>\s\S+", message)
for x in matches:
    print(x)
# <@U0104FGR7SL> test111
# <@U0106LSJ> test33
```

Comment: Wow Thank you~!!

Comment: @김동원 No problem, if my answer helped you can mark it as correct :)

Comment: @김동원 You should consider using a more generic solution if your strings mayb contain more words than one after `<@U...>` substrings. See mine and Jan's.

Answer (score 0):

Another one - using the newer `regex` module which supports splitting by lookarounds:

```
import regex as re

string = "<@U0104FGR7SL> test111 <@U0106LSJ> test33"
parts = re.split(r'(?<!\A)(?=<@)', string)
print(parts)
```

This yields

```
['<@U0104FGR7SL> test111 ', '<@U0106LSJ> test33']
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/4Wkgzv/1).

Answer (score 0):

You may use either of the two [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html) solutions:

```
re.split(r'\s+(?=<@U[^>]+>)', message)    # Any Python version, if matches are whitespace separated
[x.strip() for x in re.split(r'(?=<@U[^>]+>)', message) if x] # Starting with Python 3.7
```

NOTE: In Python 3.7, `re.split` finally was fixed to split with empty matches.

**Details**

- `\s+` -  1+ whitespaces
- `(?=<@U[^>]+>)` - a positive lookahead that requires `<@U`, 1+ chars other than `>` and then `>` immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/vN12Gt):

```
import re
message = '<@U0104FGR7SL> test111 <@U0106LSJ> test33'
print ( re.split(r'\s+(?=<@U[^>]+>)', message) )
# => '<@U0104FGR7SL> test111', '<@U0106LSJ> test33']
print ( [x.strip() for x in re.split(r'(?=<@U[^>]+>)', message) if x] )
# => '<@U0104FGR7SL> test111', '<@U0106LSJ> test33']
```